# Rename a python class with rope using a python script

Tags: python, refactoring, rename, offset, rope

Given a folder `myproj` with a file `myclass.py`

```
myproj
-- __init__.py
-- myclass.py
```

where `myclass.py` contains the following class definition

```
class MyClass:
    pass
```

I want to rename the class from `MyClass` to `MyClass2` with [rope](https://github.com/python-rope/rope).

If I know that the offset of the class name is `6`, then I could rename the class as follows

```
import rope.base.project
import rope.refactor.rename


proj = rope.base.project.Project('myproj')
res = proj.get_module('myclass').get_resource()
change = rope.refactor.rename.Rename(proj, res, 6).get_changes('MyClass2')
print(change.get_description())
```

**Question:** How do I rename a class with rope knowing only the name of the class `MyClass` (but not knowing the offset of `MyClass`)?

**Edit:**

Here is one way to do it

```
offset = res.read().index('MyClass')
```

Answer (score 0):

Rope is primarily intended for use in an IDE, where the user is refactoring interactively with text editor cursor pointed to the object that the user wants to refactor, not for programmatic refactoring.

With that said, if you want to do something like this, you can use the `get_definition_location()` method to get the closest line number:

```
mod = proj.get_module('myclass')
name = mod.get_attribute('MyClass')
pymod, lineno = name.get_definition_location()
lineno_start, lineno_end = pymod.logical_lines.logical_line_in(lineno)
 
offset = pymod.resource.read().index(name.pyobject.get_name(), pymod.lines.get_line_start(lineno))

change = rope.refactor.rename.Rename(proj, pymod.get_resource(), offset).get_changes('MyClass2')
```

It's going to be slightly more reliable than trying to get the global offset using `index()`, which can be easily fooled by matching text in docstrings/comments.

Disclosure: I am the primary maintainer of Rope